# Angular2: nested form group

Tags: angular, angular2-forms

I've created this form:

```
this.cardForm = this.fb.group({
    number: ['', Validators.compose([Validators.required, this.validateCardNumber])],
    holderName: ['', Validators.required],
    expiry: this.fb.group({
      expirationMonth: ['', Validators.required],
      expirationYear: ['', Validators.required],
    }),
```

As you can see, I've created a nested form group named `expiry`. Into my template:

```
<form [formGroup]="cardForm" novalidate="novalidate" (ngSubmit)="onSave()">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="cardnumber">Card number</label>
    <input
        type="text"
        formControlName="number"
        placeholder="Card number"
        name="cardnumber"
        class="input-transparent form-control">
  </div>
  ...
  <div class="form-group" formGroupName="expiry">
    <label for="expirationmonth">Expiration month</label>
    <select2 id="default-select"
      name="expirationmonth"
      [data]="months$ | async"
      [width]="250"
      [options]="select2Options">
    </select2>

    <label for="expirationyear">Expiration year</label>
    <select2 id="default-select2"
      name="expirationyear"
      [data]="years$ | async"
      [width]="250"
      [options]="select2Options">
    </select2>
  </div>
```

I'm getting this error:

```
ERROR Error: formGroup expects a FormGroup instance. Please pass one in.

   Example:


<div [formGroup]="myGroup">
  <input formControlName="firstName">
</div>

In your class:

this.myGroup = new FormGroup({
   firstName: new FormControl()
});
```

Any ideas?

Comment: we need more code, when is `this.cardForm = this.fb.group(...)` called ?

Comment: Add code for select2 component

Comment: @n00dl3, it's called on constructor's component.

Comment: @yurzui. You can find documentation [here](https://github.com/NejcZdovc/ng2-select2).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your view is getting loaded before your `this.cardForm` is set in your component side.

Try to put `*ngIf`:

```
<form *ngIf="cardForm" [formGroup]="cardForm" novalidate="novalidate" (ngSubmit)="onSave()">
```

Or try to encapsulate in a div with `*ngIf`:

```
  <div *ngIf="cardForm">
    <form [formGroup]="cardForm" novalidate="novalidate" (ngSubmit)="onSave()">

    </form>
   </div>
```